# How to dynamically set task routes over celery tasks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, celery, celery-task

I have an API endpoint which takes some data from the user and processes it with 1 or more celery workers.

For example, there are 3 different tasks:

```
@celery.task
def a(data):
    res = do_a_work(data)
    if res.status:
         b.apply_async(res)
    else:
         return {'message': 'a task failed'}


@celery.task
def b(data):
    res = do_b_work(data)
    if res.status:
        c.apply_async(res)
    else:
         return {'message': 'b task failed'}


@celery.task
def c(data):
    res = do_c_work(data)
    return {'result': res}
```

API endpoint submits task to either `a` or `b` depending on the data.

Possible flows:

- `a` -> `b` -> `c` -> result
- `b` -> `c` -> result
- `a` -> result (if `a` status is False)
- `a` -> `b` -> result (if `b` status is False)
- `b` -> result (if `b` status is False)

I was planning to use celery chains where I can define which tasks should be executed on that data. But the problem is that I did not find a way to stop the processing if task `a` or task `b` status is False.

Other way was to submits additional task from inside the tasks as in the task example, but the problem is that user needs to get a task_id with which later on he can get the result.

Is there a third approach I could use to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A `chord` is the right way to do this, you just have to rewrite your `do_a_work` and `do_b_work` to raise exceptions and not return a `True`/`False` value.  Once you rewrite those functions to raise exceptions, you can write your flow using chords and set error.

for a call to `a` you might do something like the beloe

```
chord(chord(a.s(data), b.s()).on_error(handle_a_error.s()), c.s()).on_error(handle_b_error.s())
```